# in madison island demo, some words aren't being translated

Tags: theme, rwd, magento-1.9

I need madison island theme in Spanish . But some words are in English
For example, say "account ", "cart " in the header..
other texts, for example : "empty cart" , is not in spanish..

ideas ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to translate? Do you look for a good spanish translation package?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a csv file of your language and upload it onto app/locale/your language folder

Comment: Try http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html?id=12816&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=spanish&t=0&p=1

Comment: PLease accept this answer if it is useful to you @marcel rodriguez